# 'Safely remove hardware' causes laptop to go into standby

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, pcmcia

I have a WinXPSP3 laptop, and it has a wifi PCMCIA card (the internal original died.)  When I go to safely remove hardware, and choose it, the laptop goes into standby mode, every time.  We have another laptop of the same model, and doing that with that card does the same thing.  Is this normal?  Or is the PCMCIA card going?  Because wifi works fine through it on at least one of the laptops.

Thanks,
Kev

Comment: Is the wireless connection active when you do the "Safely Remove Hardware"?

Comment: No, it's disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably done this already, but do you have the latest drivers for the PCMCIA card?

This sounds like the kind of problem updating drivers can solve.

Comment: I hadn't actually tried this, because we hadn't encountered this problem before, but I'll give it a shot.  Thanks.